# Can I get the Instagram access_token in a rails rake task?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, instagram

I would like to use the Instagram gem in a rake task that runs once a day to get the latest posts of a particular hash tag.

In looking at the documentation of the Instagram API you need an access_token to do just about anything meaningful.

The documentation gives an example of using "curl" to get an access_token and I'm wondering how I would translate that example into ruby so if my rails app doesn't have a toke already I can get one this way.

Here is the curl example giving on the following page of the Instagram API

```
    curl \-F 'client_id=CLIENT-ID' \
    -F 'client_secret=CLIENT-SECRET' \
    -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
    -F 'redirect_uri=YOUR-REDIRECT-URI' \
    -F 'code=CODE' \https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token

If successful, this call will return a neatly packaged OAuth Token that you can use to make authenticated calls to the API. We also include the user who just authenticated for your convenience:

{
    "access_token": "fb2e77d.47a0479900504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d",
    "user": {
        "id": "1574083",
        "username": "snoopdogg",
        "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1574083_75sq_1295469061.jpg"
    }
}
```

I was thinking I could use something like URI.parse() and then open() on the uri but that doesn't seem to do the trick. I get a 404 when trying that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue hinges on the HTTP verb being used. I believe that open will make the request using GET, while the curl example is POSTing the values.

I don't have API credentials for Instagram, so I can't test this, but I believe that if you were to try using [Net::HTTPSession](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html), in particular the post_form method, you might have more luck.

Something along the lines of:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

form_data = {
  'client_id' => 'CLIENT-ID',
  'client_secret' => 'CLIENT-SECRET',
  'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
  'redirect_uri' => 'YOUR-REDIRECT-URI',
  'code' => 'CODE'
}

uri = URI('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token')
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, form_data)

puts res
```

Alternatively, you might try something like [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) to make the call.

Comment: If I run your example in the rails consol I get a EOFError: end of file reached
 from /Users/mwallace/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:135:in `read_nonblock'

Comment: Actually URI() should be URI.parse() I think and if I do that I get the following error in the console "Connection reset by peer"